# How to make Empathy to support Unicode names in Jabber?

Tags: empathy, unicode, jabber

If I use non-latin letters to name a Jabber contact, then in chat windows (and in contact list too after I restart) they are displayed as &#nnn; codes, not as letters I've written. Is this fixable? Can I configure Empathy to use UTF-8 for non-ascii characters in Jabber?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bug in Empathy. Consider filing a bug report in their [bugtracker](http://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi) (choose component *Telepathy* — it's the backend library of Empathy).

Comment: Done. https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33202